# Throwing a exception while compiling the program to test as going

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, throw

Working on program that calculates the "Volunteer of the Year" by totaling weekly hours from a .txt and then seeing if they are above average volunteer hours that week and awarding points for both. I am throwing an exception with an array being out of bounds and can't figure out why...

```
public class volunteerOfTheYear {
//declaring int name for indexing because the name will always be in the first
//postion of the array at nameOfArray[i][0]
final static int NAME = 0;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException{
    //declare file handle
    File inputText = new File("volunteerFile.txt");
    //get Scanner from method
    Scanner input = getInput(inputText);
    //convert file to 2-d array
    String[][] volunteerChart = getvolunteerChart(input);
    //calculate weekly averages and store in array for comprarison
    double[] weeklyAverages = new double[53];
    int week = 1;
    do{
        weeklyAverages[week] = getAverageWeeklyHours(volunteerChart, week);
        week++;
    }while(week < 52);

    //compare volunteer's volunteer hours to weekly averages and calculate points for week
    //and total volunter's points
    int[] totalPoints = new int [25];
    totalPoints = getVolunteerPoints(volunteerChart, weeklyAverages, week);
    //display VOFT


}
/**
 * 
 * @param textFile
 * @return input
 * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
 */
public static Scanner getInput(File textFile) throws FileNotFoundException{
    Scanner input = new Scanner(textFile);
    return input;
}
/**
 * 
 * @param input
 * @return volunteerNamesAndHours 
 */
public static String[][] getvolunteerChart(Scanner input){
    String[][] volunteerNamesAndHours = new String [25][53];
    int ID = 0;
    int week;
    do{
        volunteerNamesAndHours[ID][NAME] = input.next();
            for(week = 1; week < 53; week++){
                 volunteerNamesAndHours[ID][week] = Integer.toString(input.nextInt());
            }
        ID++;    
    }
    while(ID <= 24);

    return volunteerNamesAndHours;        

}
/**
 * 
 * @param volunteerHours
 * @param week
 * @return 
 */
public static double getAverageWeeklyHours(String[][] volunteerHours, int week){
    double weekTotal = 0;
    //for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++ ){
    int i = 0;
    do{
        double hours = Double.parseDouble(volunteerHours[i][week]);
        weekTotal = hours + weekTotal;
        i++;
    }while(i < 26);
    double weeklyAverage = weekTotal / 25;
    return weeklyAverage;
}
/**
 * 
 * @param volunteerHours
 * @param weeklyAverages
 * @param week
 * @return totalPoints;
 */

public static int[] getVolunteerPoints(String[][] volunteerHours, double[] weeklyAverages, int week){
    int [] totalPoints = new int[25];
    int personID = 0;
    do{   
        for(week = 0; week < 53; week++){
            if(weeklyAverages[week+ 1] < Integer.parseInt(volunteerHours[personID][week]))
                totalPoints[personID] = Integer.parseInt(volunteerHours[personID][week]) + totalPoints[personID] ;

        }
        personID++;
        }while(personID < 25);    
    return totalPoints;
}
```

}

Comment: *Where* is the exception being thrown?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 25
 at jasonsiboleproject4.volunteerOfTheYear.getAverageWeeklyHours(volunteerOfTheYear.java:93)
 at jasonsiboleproject4.volunteerOfTheYear.main(volunteerOfTheYear.java:39)
Java Result: 1

Comment: And what is line 93???

Comment: weeklyAverages[week] = getAverageWeeklyHours(volunteerChart, week);

Comment: No, line 93 is *inside* method getAverageWeeklyHours, as can plainly be seen by the exception stack.

Comment: Probably line 93 is here: `Double.parseDouble(volunteerHours[i][week]);`.  You'll notice that the failing index value is 25, and the first index of volunteerHours must fall between 0 and 24.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrays in Java (and most other languages) index from 0 not 1, and so the highest index is one less than the array size.

So weeklyAverages[week + 1] (in getVolunteerPoints) is able to go out of bounds when week = 52.

Comment: So do I use a seperate counter in the loop or do I just subtract 1 from week?

Comment: Limit week to 51 at maximum `for(week = 0; week < 52; week++)` or put in an if function that does something different for week 52. There is no week 53, so you have to decide how your logic deals with that.